# Spring MVC. Redirect page

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a controller wich handles URL studentEdit.html. When I pass to controller value 'get' using AJAX I need to redirect to another page viewStudents.html, but nothing happens. I stay on the same page. The method returns the ModelAndView, but why it does not redirect to another page I do not know.

I also tried to set url as:

redirect:viewStudents.html and redirect:viewStudents

but it did not helped.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/studentEdit.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getStudentProfile(@RequestParam(value = "get", required = false) String get) {

    if(get != null && get.equals("get")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewStudents.html");
    } else {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("studentEdit"); 
        return mav;
    }
}


function getStudent() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/IRSystem/studentProfileEdit.html",
                data: "get=" + 'get',
                success: function(response) {

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert('Error' + e);
                }

            });
        }
```

I would appreciate any information, thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this on the server side?  You should just use Javascript to redirect if you're not actually retrieving any data from the server.

Comment: You are redirecting the AJAX request itself. It is not possible to re-locate the page with this approach.

Comment: You can tackle this problem by adding a header e.g. `X-Redirect-Url:/my/redirect` to the response and act on that value in your success callback. If your environment lets you of course.

Comment: I need to retrieve information from database and then redirect with this information to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect to another page after request, there is no need to use AJAX.

A simple link should be enough:

```
<a href="/IRSystem/studentProfileEdit.html?get=get">click me</a>
```

What happens when you click on the link:

- a GET request to `/IRSystem/studentProfileEdit.html` is performed
- `get=get` is passed as request data
- by default, user is redirected to link's `href` (i.e `/IRSystem/studentProfileEdit.html`), but you can redirect him somewhere else

Assuming the rest of your code is correct, using `<a>` as mentioned above together with `redirect:/viewStudents.html` should redirect as desired.

Also [check the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) about `redirect:` prefix to make sure your redirect is interpreted correctly.